# React trying to use .map to populate data from multiple APIs into the same mapped container

Tags: reactjs, fetch, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to practice integrating data from separate APIs, but I'm having trouble conceptualizing what the right way is to do so.

Basically, I have two sample APIs I'm fetching from:
1. const API = 'https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query='; (this.state.hits)
const DEFAULT_QUERY = 'redux';
and 
2. https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50  (this.state.randomPeople)

I pull them into their own arrays in state via a method called in componentDid Mount.

```
this.state = {
      hits: [],
      randomPeople: [],

    };
```

Ideally, I'd like to map over both of them and have data available from each .map result to populate in a single container, something like:

```
<div>
<img src={random.thumbnailPic}/>
<h3>{random.name.first}</h3>
<h3>{random.name.last}</h3>
<p>{hit.title}</p>
</div>
```

Just not sure how to approach this the best way. I have only mapped over one data source when populating the results to a container. Should I combine the two arrays and store them together in state? I looked at Lodash, would that work here? Or is there a better way to accomplish this that I just haven't found?

Right now I just have them right on top of another in render() :

```
{hits.map(hit => (
    <div key={hit.objectID}>
         <a href={hit.url}>{hit.title}</a>
     </div>
 ))}

 {randomPeople.map(rando => (
     <div key={random.email}>
         <img src={random.picture.medium} />
          <h3>Author: {random.name.first} {random.name.last}</h3>
      </div>
  ))}
```

And here are my methods:

```
fetchHits = () => {
    fetch(API + DEFAULT_QUERY)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {

          return response.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Something went wrong ... ');
        }
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ hits: data.hits, isLoading: false }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  };

  fetchRandomPeople = () => {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/?results=50')
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ randomPeople: data.results }));
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchRandomPeople();
    this.fetchHits();
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're assuming that hits and randompeople are going to be the same length, or if you can somehow align the two arrays, you could add the index parameter to your .map() function:

```
{randomPeople.map((rando, i) => (
  <div key={rando.email}>
    <img src={rando.thumbnailPic}/>
    <h3>{rando.name.first}</h3>
    <h3>{rando.name.last}</h3>
    <p>{hits[i].title}</p>
  </div>
)}
```

Comment: There are obviously other cases where this could work too!

Comment: "cannot read property 'title' of undefined." hits is from state, just like randomPeople is. Could it be because the arrays are not the same size?

Comment: If randomPeople is bigger then yes that would be the case, another possibility is that `hits` hasn't been fetched yet, so it's still an empty array. I would put some validation at the top of `render()` to return null if `this.state.isLoading` is still true, and initialize `isLoading: true` in your constructor

Comment: Good call, it was because the arrays were different sizes. I'll mark this as the answer, but I am curious:  What is the ideal way to pull mapped data from more than two sources into the same container? Using one as an index almost seems like a workaround but I could be wrong.

Comment: It really depends on the nature of your data, and what assumptions you can make about it. You haven't really revealed the purpose of the application (which isn't a bad thing), but if you want these two sources to be bound together you could try using async/await and initializing a single array of objects containing fields from both sources? Then just map over the one? You really have to think about the uses of your data and application!

Comment: The purpose of this app (it's just a React Component really), is to find the best way to populate multiple data GETs into the same container. The APIs here are HackNoon's and a Random Person Generator. A more practical example might be pulling a movie title from one api, and maybe pictures of the movie pulled from a different api. 
But I see what you mean... eventually there will need to be a purpose and that is where the real decisions will need to be made in regard to how best sort the incoming API data. This is a different topic entirely I know, but thanks again for your help here.